# Is there a split pane library for angular that does not rely on other frameworks other than AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, split, pane, splitpane

I'm looking for a split-pane library - something that will let me have 2 tables on a screen, and the user can drag the middle divider to show more of one table or the other.

I know there are libraries out there that do this, like the shagstrom one, but I was looking for something that didn't rely on jQuery. Does one exist, and if so, can you please point me to it?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout - this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Split.js](http://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/) which have no dependencies and works very well.

Simple example:

```
Split(['#one', '#two'], {
    sizes: [25, 75],
    minSize: 200
});
```

This is not an angular librairy but but can easily integrate it inside a directive.

Comment: Could you please take a look into you repository [angular-split](https://github.com/bertrandg/angular-split) and if it's possible to add some new contributors ? It seems that current contributors aren't not interested in developing this package but a lot of merge requests awaits to be reviewed and merged [example](https://github.com/bertrandg/angular-split/pull/204)

Comment: you're right > https://github.com/bertrandg/angular-split/issues/237

Comment: Awesome! You are the best

Comment: @bertrandg Even when the library is now in the hands of another maintainer, it seems like more people are needed to help this library stay alive. There are currently pull requests from 2020 that seem not to be reviewed... 

Is there a way to contribute?

Comment: @AlteSchule Sorry i'm not involved anymore in this lib but current maintainer seems to do a good job. Keep in mind that's free time for him and maybe he favors solidity than pull request features he's not totally sure about implications.. Talk to him directly on github :)

Comment: @bertrandg I did contact him. He's not open to letting others take responsibility. His argument is he has no time and his suggestion is to create pull requests he will only review when he has time. A bit contradictory since he says "he has no time"

As I've said, there have been pull requests open since 2020... Is there a way to get back that repo and pass it over to people who really care for the community?

Answer (score 2):

There is a split.js angular wrapper,angular-split that works just fine
run , here is an example, after running 
    npm install angular-split --save

Add AngularSplitModule to your app module:

```
import { AngularSplitModule } from 'angular-split';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
...
],
imports: [
AngularSplitModule,
...
],
providers: [...],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { AngularSplitModule } from 'angular-split'

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
styles: [`
:host {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: grey;
 }
 `],
  template: `
  <split direction="horizontal">
      <split-area [size]="30">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
      </split-area>
      <split-area [size]="70">
          <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus erro...</p>
      </split-area>
  </split>`,
})
export class App {}


@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, AngularSplitModule ],
declarations: [ App ],
bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tEjcXo?p=preview)